# Unable to set Cron for Laravel4

Tags: laravel-4, cron

I have been banging my head for last 3 days to set cron for my website. In my cpanel I have mentioned a cron which will run every 5 minutes and command is

```
wget http://www.example.com/artisan cron:run
```

In my artisan I have added

```
Artisan::add(new CronRunCommand);
```

And CronRunCommand.php is

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
class CronRunCommand extends Command {
    protected $name = 'cron:run';
    protected $description = 'Run the scheduler';
    protected $timestamp;
    protected $messages = array();
    protected $runAt = '03:00';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->timestamp = time();
    }
    public function fire()
    {
        $this->everyFiveMinutes(function()
        {
            // In the function, you can use anything that you can use everywhere else in Laravel.
            $affectedRows = User::where('logged_in', true)->update(array('logged_in' => false)); // Not really useful, but possible
            Artisan::call('auth:clear-reminders');
            $this->messages[] = $affectedRows . ' users logged out';
        });
        $this->dailyAt('09:00', function()
        {
            Mail::send('hello', array(), function($message)
            {
                $message->to('admin@mydomain.com', 'Cron Job')->subject('I am still running!');
            });
        });
        $this->finish();
    }
    protected function finish()
    {
        // Write execution time and messages to the log
        $executionTime = round(((microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']) * 1000), 3);
        Log::info('Cron: execution time: ' . $executionTime . ' | ' . implode(', ', $this->messages));
    }
    protected function yearly(callable $callback)
    {
        if(date('m', $this->timestamp) === '01' && date('d', $this->timestamp) === '01' && date('H:i', $this->timestamp) === $this->runAt) call_user_func($callback);
    }
}
```

And in my email I am getting this message:
404 Not Found
2015-09-06 04:38:02 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2015-09-06 04:38:02--  ftp://cron/run
           => “run”
Resolving cron... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address “cron”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked absolutely fine and I have started regular emails
 wget http://www.example.com/protected/app/controllers/TestController.php